# Neural network inner/outer layer error term

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to understand neural networks and the gradient problem.

So i try to figure out the error term from the output layer and inner layer.

equation 9.3-48:
$I_q = \sum_{k=1}^{N_k} w_{jk} \cdot O_k$

equation 9.3-54:
$\frac{\partial I_q}{\partial w_{qp}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_{qp}} \sum_{p=1}^{N_p} w_{qp} \cdot O_p = O_p$

Can someone explain why its $O_p$ and not $\sum_{p=1}^{N_p} O_p$. In my mind the Summation shouldn't fall out...

Also by equation 9.3-58:
$E_Q = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sum_{q=1}^{N_Q} (r_q - O_q)^2$
$\frac{\partial E_Q}{\partial O_q} = -(r_q - O_q)$
In my mind there should be the out come $\sum -(r_q - O_q)$

I would really appreciate if someone can tell me why the summation is falling out...

I found these equations in
Gonzalez/Woods - Chapter. 9.3.3, Pages 595-619 (NN)

[image: Page 608]

Comment: Summation disappears because derivatives of all but one term are $0$. For example, for the first part, $\frac{\partial w_{qi}}{\partial w_{qj}} = 0$ if $i \neq j$ (btw I think it's bad idea to use the same variable as summation index and outside of summation)

Comment: But 9.3-54 they derive $w_{qp}$ so over the index p and q.... so they are equal to the deriving variable

Comment: Okay got it.... its bc $I_q$ has a fixed q so the derivation is only about one $w_{qp}$